# R studio crashing when importing libraries in R Markdown

Tags: r

I am having this weird issue with my R studio. It has no problem loading the below-mentioned libraries in R script but crashes when trying to import these libraries in R markdown.

Libraries:

```r
library(bnlearn)
library(Rgraphviz)
library(dplyr)
```

Error:
R Session Aborted

[image: Error Screenshot]

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I can't think of anything off hand. Can you disable all chunks and knit without crashing? If so, enable each chunk one-by-one, rendering each time, until you find the errant chunk that is causing the crash.

Comment: In addition to the comment of  r2evans: also for the chunk it is crashing comment all lines out and go line by line uncommenting. Maybe you can point out then for which of these library calls it is failing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The problem is it is failing at different chunks on different runs.

Comment: Okay. Disable all (failing) chunks except one, and comment out all lines. Then uncomment the first line and render it several times until you are comfortable that it is not failing with the frequency that you are otherwise seeing. Repeat with each consecutive line until you find a line that is periodically crashing. At this point, you will know the specific package that is causing problems. Once you know that ... reinstall it (as [`type="binary"`](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/07/01/announcing-public-package-manager/)) and see if that fixes it. If not, file a bug with its maintainers.

Comment: Or you can just preemptively reinstall all three of those packages as `type="binary"` (linux/macos binaries are available here: https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/07/01/announcing-public-package-manager/) and try again.